# ALLOWED_TAGS_REGEX for ng-tag-input didn't work

Tags: angularjs, ng-tags-input

I want the input tag only have the following:
Upper case(A-Z), lower case(a-z), number and -*+.
For example here is valid tag: Engineer9*-+ (upper, lower case, digit, _,-,+) 
but it didn't work.

```
<tags-input ng-model="tag" allowed-tags-pattern="[a-zA-Z0-9_-+]+">
```

Any idea how to fix this regex.
Thanks,
K

Comment: I guess the - sign between _ and + is causing the problem

Comment: Can you try `[a-zA-Z0-9_\-+]+`

Comment: Here is simlar question and answer to it: [Reqular Expression](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39476110/ng-tags-input-with-allowed-tags-pattern-option-doesnt-work/40123738#40123738)