# ng-tags-input with allowed-tags-pattern option doesn't work

Tags: angularjs, ng-tags-input

I want tagname to only be in Upper case, Lower Case, Number, Characters: +_- and defined the tag-input as below with `allowed-tags-pattern="[A-Za-z0-9+_-]+"`

My try:

```
<tags-input ng-model="selectedTags"
      display-property="name"
      add-on-space="true"
      allowed-tags-pattern="[A-Za-z0-9+_-]+"
      on-invalid-tag="invalidTagInput($tag)"
      on-tag-adding="addingTag($tag)"
      placeholder="{{'TAGS.SELECT' | translate}}">

      <auto-complete source="loadTags($query)"
           min-length="0"
           load-on-focus="true"
           load-on-empty="true"
           max-results-to-show="32">
      </auto-complete>
</tags-input>
```

But allowed-tags-pattern="[A-Za-z0-9+*-]+" didn't work, any suggestion what is value of allowed-tags-pattern that allow the tag to have upper case, lower case, number, characters(-*+) ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this regular expression **^[A-Z|a-z|0-9|+_-]+$**

```
<tags-input ng-model="tags" allowed-tags-pattern="^[A-Z|a-z|0-9|\+\_\-]+$">
     <auto-complete source="loadTags($query)"></auto-complete>
</tags-input>
```

You are missing "start" **"^"** and "end " **"$"** tag of the regular expression.
Here is a working plunker: [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/nRjijs?p=preview)

Comment: I am not sure who voted it down. can anyone explain the reason. AsI have mentioned clearly with Plunker that it works. In description of question, it is missing "start" and "end " tag of the regular expression.